# How to identify if the current machine is ec2 or my local computer in Java

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have an application which can run locally on my computer and also on aws ec2 instance. In both the cases I need to perform 2 different operations. Is there a simple way in Java to identify if the current application is running on ec2 or local machine?

its different than the suggested answer because I dont have the HttpWebRequest etc access in my code.

Comment: [How to check application runs in AWS EC2 instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907418/how-to-check-application-runs-in-aws-ec2-instance) ??

Comment: @Perdomoff Thanks for your quick response but I dont have the HttpWebRequest etc access in my code.